# iOS programmatically generated view has hidden constraints causing conflicts with auto layout

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

This is a very basic view that links to a view controller. The view has a single UILabel that is placed with coded constraints. The code actually runs correctly, but the console is registering a constraint conflict, and I can't figure out which part of the code is creating the conflict.

**LocationView.m file**

```
#import "LocationView.h"

@implementation LocationView

@synthesize locationTitle;    

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
        locationTitle = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        [locationTitle setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        locationTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self addSubview:locationTitle];

        NSDictionary *viewLocationTitle = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(locationTitle);

        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[locationTitle]|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:0
                                                                       views:viewLocationTitle]];

        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[locationTitle(50)]|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:0
                                                                       views:viewLocationTitle]];

- (void)updateConstraints {
    [super updateConstraints]; 
}
@end
```

**Console error**

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109510990 V:|-(NSSpace(20))-[UILabel:0x10950b660]   (Names: '|':LocationView:0x10950acc0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109510c10 V:[UILabel:0x10950b660(50)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x109510c60 V:[UILabel:0x10950b660]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':LocationView:0x10950acc0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x108f3ae00 h=--& v=--& V:[LocationView:0x10950acc0(568)]>"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are saying that you want it to be 50 points high AND pinned to the top and bottom of the super view (you included the | before and after your label).

Try changing your vertical constraint to

```
@"V:|-[locationTitle(50)]"
```

Or you can add a lower priority to one of the constraints, but I'm guessing this is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this string, "V:|-[locationTitle(50)]|". Tis says that locationTitle is a standard distance from the top of the view (20 points I think), and 0 points from the bottom, but it's only 50 points high -- that can only be satisfied if the superview is 70 points tall. You probably want to remove either the top or bottom constraint (or the height if you want to stretch it over the whole view mini that 20 point top space).